# Can't use amsthm option with ntheorem, and no QED markers

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

I'm trying to get QED markers to show up at the end of a proof only, using `ntheorem` but run into a couple of problems.
First, using the `amsthm` option with `ntheorem` doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twosided]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[standard, amsthm, amsmath]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
    A really insightful theorem.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{proof}~\\
    $\forall g \in G \ldots$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

gives the following errors:

```
! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.
! Latex Error: Command \proof already defined.Or name \end... illegal
```

When I remove the `\usepackage{amsthm}` and `amsthm` from the `ntheorem` options it will build fine, but still no QED markers at the end of the proof.

Using the `thmmarks` option with `ntheorem` puts QED symbols at the ends of theorems as well, which I don't want.

Comment: Amsthm and ntheorem are incompatible, use one or the other.

Comment: the `ntheorem` documentation does say that `amsthm` and `ntheorem` can be used together,  but if the `amsthm` option is chosen, the `standard` option *cannot* be used.  that is the source of the duplicate `proof` definition.  (`ntheorem' documentation, p.16, section 3.2.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsthm` option yields compatibility with the theorem layout commands of the `amsthm` package, but don't use both packages. The `amsthm` option is not compatible with the `standard` option. The qed symbols are activated by the `thmmarks` option. Furthermore, I recommend loading the `thref` option to activate extended referencing features.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twosided]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[standard, thref, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}%

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
    A really insightful theorem.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{proof}~\\
    $\forall g \in G \ldots$
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]